# Bash script for listing the files in a directory in a specific format witht the BASH shell

Tags: bash, ls

I am currently working on some C++ code on a GNU/Linux system and my source-code folder is filled with .cpp files and .h files.

In general for this code, every `.cpp` file has a corresponding `.h` header file, but not necessarily
vice versa. In the output below `--` indicates that there is no corresponding .cpp file for the listed header file

I would like to either write a bash script to do this by say defining an extra flag in my .bashrc / .zshrc , such that the 
listing of the files occurs in this format. Say I have 7 files, some `.cpp` and some `.h`

```
$ listscript
hello1.cpp hello1.h
hello2.cpp hello2.h
   --      hello3.h 
hello4.cpp hello4.h
```

Comment: I think you'd rather write a bash script to do this rather than trying to get ls to do it.

Comment: Yeah a bash script solution would also work for me.

Comment: Actually, why don't you write such a tool in C++ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare files=(*)
declare file= left= right= width=10
declare -A listed=()
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ $file == *.h ]]; then
        continue
    elif (( ${#file} > width )); then
        width=${#file}
    fi
done
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${listed[$file]} == 1 ]]; then
        continue
    elif [[ $file == *.cpp ]]; then
        left=$file right=${file%.cpp}.h
    elif [[ $file == *.h ]]; then
        left=${file%.h}.cpp right=$file
    else
        left=$file right=
    fi

    [[ $left ]]     && listed["$left"]=1
    [[ $right ]]    && listed["$right"]=1

    [[ -e $left ]]  || left='--'
    [[ -e $right ]] || right='--'

    printf "%-*s %s\n" "$width" "$left" "$right"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be a nicer solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since every `.h` file may or may not have a corresponding `.cpp` file,
just iterate over all `.h` files. For each one, you can check if
the corresponding `.cpp` file exists and use "---" if not.

```
for fh in *.h; do
    fcpp=${fh/%.h/.cpp}
    [ -f "$fcpp" ] || fcpp="---"
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$fcpp" "$fh"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about (in `bash`):

```
for f in $(ls -1 *.{cpp,h} | sed -e 's/.cpp//;s/.h//' | sort -u)
do 
    [ -f "${f}.cpp" ] && printf "%s " "${f}.cpp" || printf " -- "
    [ -f "${f}.h" ] &&  printf "%s" "${f}.h" || printf " -- "; 
    printf "\n"
done
```

Comment: `for f in $(ls...)` is [bad](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). So is [using `&& ||`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) as ternary operator, or [not putting quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target) around variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

# run like this:
# ./file_lister DIRECTORY

for i in $1/*.h
do
        name=`basename $i .h`
        if [ -e $name.cpp ]
        then
          ls $name.*
        else
          echo "-- " `basename $i`
        fi
done
```